# JWT access token is not valid - Invalid credentials

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm having trouble generating a valid JWT access token in my Symfony project. I'm using the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle to handle JWT authentication, and I'm trying to generate a token for a user who is registered by phone number rather than email (the application accepts the two methods of authentication, so I can't replace the `user_identity_field` in *lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml*). The problem is that the generated token always has an empty username field, and is therefore not valid.

Here's my verifyOtpCode() function:

```php
public function verifyOtpCode(string $phoneNumber, string $code,
                                  JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTManager,
                                  JWTCreatedEvent $event)
    {
        $otp = $this->otpCodeRepository->findOneBy(['phoneNumber' => $phoneNumber], ['createdAt' => 'DESC']);
        if (!$otp) {
            return ['error' => 'OTP code not found.'];
        }

        $now = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        if ($otp->getExpirationDate() < $now) {
            return ['error' => 'OTP code expired.'];
        }

        if ($otp->getCode() !== $code) {
            return ['error' => 'Invalid OTP code.'];
        }
        //Check if user is already registered by phone number
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Farmer::class)->findOneBy(['phone' => $phoneNumber]);
        if($user){
            //User already registered, create the token and return it with the user data
            $farmer = new Farmer();
            $farmer->setPhone($phoneNumber);
            $payload = $event->getData();
            $payload['username'] = $farmer->getPhone();

            $event->setData($payload);
            $token = $this->JWTManager->create($farmer);
            return $this->authenticationSuccessHandler
                ->onAuthenticationSuccess($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest(), $token);
        }
        //User not registered, return just a success message and continue with the registration process
        return new JsonResponse(['message' => 'OTP code verified, user not registered.'], Response::HTTP_PERMANENTLY_REDIRECT);
    }
```

I've tried to set the username field to the user's phone number, but it doesn't seem to be working. Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!